# why does my app generated with pynsist using snap 7 dont open

Tags: python, nsis, pynsist, snap7

Hi im trying to make a nsis installer via pynsist but i dont know how to add the snap7 library it makes the file but when i try to run my script generated by pynsist dont open the file.

here is my cfg file.

```
[Application]
name=JIG Sensor Overview
version=0.1
# How to launch the app - this calls the 'main' function from the 'myapp' package:
entry_point=JIGOverview:main
icon=JIGOverview.ico

[Python]
version=3.9.9
bitness=64

[Include]
pypi_wheels = python-snap7==1.1
     Pillow==9.0.0
# Packages from PyPI that your application requires, one per line
packages = requests
     snap7
     PIL
     tkinter
    _tkinter



# To bundle packages which don't publish wheels, or to include directly wheel files
# from a directory, see the docs on the config file.

# Other files and folders that should be installed
files = lib
    SRC/
```

Comment: Does snap7 have any external dependencies that need to be included in the installer? Do you get any errors from this?

Comment: If the installed app doesn't seem to start at all, it normally means there's an uncaught exception. [See the docs](https://pynsist.readthedocs.io/en/latest/installers.html#uncaught-exceptions) for how to find the error message. It looks like you're using tkinter, though - that's unfortunately kind of tricky for Pynsist ([see the FAQ](https://pynsist.readthedocs.io/en/latest/faq.html#packaging-with-tkinter)).